# Solaris daemon runlevels

Tags: solaris, daemon, runlevel

There is this service I need to start up automatically whenever the my solaris server is restarted. I know I should set the runlevel as 3, but will it matter if I set the service to run on all runlevels(0 to 6)? if so, what would be the problem if I do that?

Comment: Runlevels are deprecated in Solaris 10, consider using SMF to start your service.

Comment: Even if they were, what would be the issue If I put a daemon in all runlevels?

Comment: No effect - if the service does not require other services.  svcs -xv <servicenhname>  will show you the related services.  The service will not start if it has external requirements that are not met.  PS: this is a poor question for SO because: not about programming, too broad to answer.  Ask it on serverfault and mention the service explicitly by name and why you require it

Answer (score 1):

Important documentation for migrating from runlevels to SMF - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36820/index.html (Managing System Services in Oracle Solaris 11.2) and

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36883/smf-5.html#scrolltoc
which is the manpage describing the SMF facility in general.